# graph api is not returning users details suddenly for me. (might be from today)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It is web base application.
The first page is asking for login. Once they click the login button, everything is going on with ajax.

In the ajax request,

```
 $user = $facebook->getUser();
```

This is giving proper user id.

```
 if ($user) {
    try {
        $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
        $user_id = $fbme['id'];
    } 
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {           
         error_log($e);
         $user = null;
    }
}
```

The below line was working before.
Now it is end in the catch block. So I am not able the user details.

What could be the problem?
Since I didn't make changes in the script so far, It is suddenly stopped working.

Comment: If its ending in the catch block, atleast show us the error you are logging.

Comment: This is the error : An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Comment: Why this line is not working? $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');

Comment: I didn't create / change anything. It was actually working. Today only I am facing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access token may be out of date, I suggest something like this:

```
try {
    $data['user_profile'] = $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');

    }catch (Exception $e){
       $this->facebook->setAccessToken($this->facebook->getAccessToken());
    try {

        if($this->facebook->getUser()) {
        $this->facebook->api(array('method' =>'auth.revokeAuthorization' ));
       }

    }catch(Exception $e) {
        redirect(...);
    }
    redirect(...);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a facebook bug.  They fixed it last night.  If you update your facebook php SDK it will work.